# How to create PDF file with UTF-8 in Google App Engine Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, pdf, utf-8, pisa

I am creating PDF file in Google App Engine using Python 2.7. I am using template html file to generate PDF content. I think I marked that I am using UTF-8 coding in every step however created PDF cannot display it properly. So far I tested in on localhost only. Could you advice me what I am doing wrong?

1. Template document. I set in file properties UTF-8 coding and put utf-8 charset in metadata.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
       Działając
   </body>
   <html>
   ```
2. Code creating PDF file has marked UTF-8 coding in every possible place. Cource code file is also UTF-8.

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   ... code skipped

   #    f = codecs.open(os.path.join(APP_TEMPLATES, 'test.html'), encoding ='utf-8')
   #    fdata = f.read()
   #    f.close()    
   #   htmpPage = render_template_string(fdata, encoding='utf-8')

   htmpPage = render_template('test.html', encoding='utf-8')

   pdfOUTPUT = StringIO.StringIO()

   pisa.pisaDocument(htmpPage,dest=pdfOUTPUT, encoding='utf-8')
   #    pisa.CreatePDF(htmpPage, dest=pdfOUTPUT, encoding='UTF-8')

   response = make_response(pdfOUTPUT.getvalue())
   response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='test' + '.pdf')
   response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8')
   ```
3. Created PDF does not display string correctly
   [image]

Comment: Does it work outside of App Engine?  Just try it in regular Python code on your computer to narrow down the source of possible problems.